# CGAL-implementation of the intersection of two cubic (planar) Bezier/Splines offsets

Tags: cgal

CGAL's manual suggests that there is no such implementation, if you know anything more let me know

N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested:

"There is a CGAL implementation of an exact arrangement of Bezier curves ( http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Arrangement_on_surface_2/Chapter_main.html#Subsection_32.6.7 )" cheers Iddo Hanniel

Comment: Anchor in link seems broken. Was this linking to a specific example of intersecting two cubic bezier curves using CGAL?

Comment: Hi Alec, yes it was. Most likely this https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/classCGAL_1_1Arr__Bezier__curve__traits__2.html

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like two questions, rather than one:

(1) How to intersect two planar cubic Bezier curves

(2) How to offset a planar cubic Bezier curve

I don't understand the statement that "there is no implementation". Maybe they just mean that there is no implementation in CGAL.

Both problems require numerical methods or approximation -- neither one has a closed-form solution.

But they are both well-known problems with many workable (approximate) solutions available. Searching for "intersect Bezier curves" or "offset Bezier curve" will return dozens of useful references and code samples.

If you want to solve these problems using CGAL ...

(1) Intersection. This is basically a root-finding problem, and CGAL has a bivariate root finder called AlgebraicKernel_d_2::Solve_2.

(2) Offsetting. Could perhaps be done using the Minkowski sum functions. Look at approximated_offset_2, for example. The result will be polygonal, but that might be good enough for your purposes. This is really a curve approximation problem, for which CGAL has no tools, as far as I can see.

Comment: my question specifically targets CGAL. As you say there is plenty of material online

Comment: added some CGAL suggestions to the answer

Comment: BTW, some modularity in CGAL would be great! see http://www.cgal.org/project_ideas.html#modularity

Answer (score 0):

for a great explanation of the elaborate math behind the problem browse https://raphlinus.github.io/curves/2022/09/09/parallel-beziers.html